# Concatenate a style with a variable

Tags: php, html

Trying to use a variable with style to set a position.

Have researched it, but have yet to find an answer.

```php
<div href="#" id="FabofLifeBox" style="position-top: "+ $ptop; +" position-left: "+$pleft; +" class="zoom">
```

the `$ptop` and the `$pleft` are the variables I am trying to set the position in the style statement.

Comment: HTML doesn't have variables. You'll need a programming language to do this.

Comment: @Quentin, correct.. I am using php, but I stopped php to try and process it.  I could not get php to do it either.     here is the php I tried as well:                                echo '<div href="#" id="FabofLifeBox" style="position-top: '. $ptop .' position-left: ' . $pleft ." class="zoom">';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open and close PHP tags and this is very straightforward.

```
... your php code ?>

    <div id="FabofLifeBox" style="top:<?php echo $ptop; ?>px;left:<?php echo $pleft; ?>px;" class="zoom">

<?php ...your php code continues
```

Just mind that your are opening and closing PHP in the right places and this works.

ps... `position-top` and `position-left` are not valid CSS properties, I changed to `top` and `left`. `div` tag also does not support `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try blending Javascript and PHP, an example of setting the position-top:

```
//php variable declared up here
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use JavaScript</h2>

<p id="FabofLifeBox">This some random text</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("FabofLifeBox").style="position-top:<?php echo $ptop ?>";
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP you added in the comments to the question would work (except for the missing semicolons between the style parameters), but there is no `position-top` or  `position-left` parameter in CSS. Try something like this instead:

```
echo '<div href="#" id="FabofLifeBox" style="top: '. $ptop .'; left: ' . $pleft . ';" class="zoom">';
```